# All rows are not inserted in server database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm uploading data from an xml file. 
All rows are uploading fine in my local server. But only some rows are inserted in server's database.

**This is my upload code**

```
/*--upload data to database--*/
if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){
    @$token=$_SESSION['token'];
    // echo 'session'.$token.'<br>';
    //echo 'form'.$_POST['token'];
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    if($token&&$_POST['token']==$token){
        $lotterydetails=array(
           $_POST['serialnumber'],
           $_POST['lotteryname'],
           $_POST['date'],
           $_POST['drawnumber'],
           $_POST['drawvenew'],
           $_POST['approvedby'],
           $_POST['approverdesig'],
           $_POST['approveroffice']
        );
        try  
        {
            $connect=lottery_db_connect();
            $connect->beginTransaction();
            /*--check for duplicate entry if found rollbak the transaction--*/
            $duplicate=$connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `daily_draw_details` WHERE `draw_date`=?");
            $duplicate->execute(array($_POST['date']));
            if($duplicate->rowCount()){
                $connect->rollBack();
                $error="Duplicate entry found!! File is already uploaded";
            }else{
                /*--insert basic data--*/
                $first=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `daily_draw_details`(`draw_serial_number`, `draw_lottery_name`, `draw_date`, `draw_number`, `draw_venuew`, `draw_approved_by`, `draw_approver_designation`, `draw_approved_office`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $first->execute($lotterydetails);
                $id=$connect->lastInsertId();

                /*--insert prize details--*/
                $second=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `draw_prize_list`(`draw_id`, `prize_no`, `prize_amount`, `prize_consolation`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                $amount=$_POST['prizeamount'];
                $conslation=$_POST['conslation'];

                /*--insert series and digit details--*/
                $third=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `draw_series_details`(`prize_id`, `prize_series_name`, `prize_lottery_number`, `prize_lottery_district`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                foreach($_POST['prizeno'] as $key=>$prize){
                    $second->execute(array($id,$prize,$amount[$key],$conslation[$key]));
                    $prizeid=$connect->lastInsertId();
                    foreach($_POST[$prize.'seriesname'] as $key=>$series){
                        $check=$connect->prepare("
                            SELECT * 
                            FROM `draw_series_details` 
                            WHERE `prize_series_name`=? 
                            AND `prize_lottery_number`=?");
                        $check->execute(array($series,$_POST[$prize.'digits'][$key]));
                        if($check->rowCount()){
                        }else{
                            $third->execute(array($prizeid,$series,$_POST[$prize.'digits'][$key],$_POST[$prize.'district'][$key]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                $connect->commit();
                check_for_saved_lottery($_POST['date']);
                pushNotificationToUsers($_POST['lotteryname'],$_POST['drawnumber']);
                $success="Lottery results uploaded successfully";
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            // $connect->rollBack();
            //$e->getMessage();
            $error="An error occured try again";
        }
    }else{
        $error="Token mismatch error is happen";
    }   
}
/*--end of upload--*/
```

Eg . If i upload 60 rows from the XML, Its only inserting 38 rows. But in localhost, all rows are uploaded successfully.

**UPDATE - Database Structure**

**draw_series_details**

```
_________________________________________
|Column                 |Type           |
-----------------------------------------
|id                     |int(11)        |    
|prize_id               |varchar(50)    |    
|prize_series_name      |varchar(20)    |        
|prize_lottery_number   |varchar(100)   |        
|prize_lottery_district |varchar(200)   |
-----------------------------------------
```

**draw_prize_list**

```
_________________________________
|Column           |Type         |
---------------------------------
|id               |int(11)      |
|draw_id          |varchar(10)  |
|prize_no         |varchar(20)  | 
|prize_amount     |varchar(200) |
|prize_consolation|varchar(10)  | 
---------------------------------
```

**daily_draw_details**

```
___________________________________________
|Column                    |Type          |
------------------------------------------- 
|id                        |int(11)       |      
|draw_serial_number        |varchar(50)   |      
|draw_lottery_name         |varchar(200)  |          
|draw_date                 |varchar(50)   |          
|draw_number               |varchar(50)   |      
|draw_venuew               |varchar(500)  |      
|draw_approved_by          |varchar(200)  |          
|draw_approver_designation |varchar(200)  |          
|draw_approved_office      |varchar(500)  |
-------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE-upload the xml file and display in html table,finally uploaded to database**

```
 //get data from xml
 $xml=simplexml_load_file($_FILES['result']['tmp_name']);
 <!--table generation starts here-->
            <?php if(isset($xml)&&!empty($xml))
            {?>
            <div class="form-group">
            <form action="profile.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="serialnumber" value="<?php echo $xml->drawserialnumber; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="lotteryname" value="<?php echo $xml->lotteryname; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $xml->drawdate; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="drawnumber" value="<?php echo $xml->shortname.'-'.$xml->drawnumber; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="drawvenew" value="<?php echo $xml->drawvenew; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="approvedby" value="<?php echo $xml->approvedby; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="approverdesig" value="<?php echo $xml->approverdesig; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="approveroffice" value="<?php echo $xml->approveroffice; ?>">
                <?php
                 echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" class="table">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Prize No</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Consolation</th>
                    <th>Series Name</th>
                    <th>Lottery Number</th>
                    <th>District</th>
                  </tr>';
                 foreach($xml->prizes as $prize){
                    foreach($prize->prizedetails as $details){
                 ?>
                <tr>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo sizeof($details->prizeticket); ?>"><?php echo $details->prizeno; ?><input type="hidden" name="prizeno[]" value="<?php echo $details->prizeno; ?>"></td>
                <td rowspan="<?php echo sizeof($details->prizeticket); ?>" ><?php echo $details->prizedesc; ?><input type="hidden" name="prizeamount[]" value="<?php echo $details->prizedesc; ?>"></td>
                <td rowspan="<?php echo sizeof($details->prizeticket); ?>" ><?php echo $details->conslation; ?><input type="hidden" name="conslation[]" value="<?php echo $details->conslation; ?>"></td>
                <?php
                  $i=1;foreach ($details->prizeticket as $tickets){
                 ?>
                <td><?php echo $tickets->seriesname; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $details->prizeno;  ?>seriesname[]" value="<?php echo $tickets->seriesname; ?>">
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $tickets->digit; ?>
                          <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $details->prizeno;  ?>digits[]" value="<?php echo $tickets->digit; ?>">
                        </td>
                             <td><?php  echo $tickets->district; ?>
                          <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $details->prizeno;  ?>district[]" value="<?php echo $tickets->district; ?>">
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                     <?php  $i++;
                  }
                 }
                }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Verfiy and upload to application" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <br><br>
                </form><?php }?>
```

Here the work flow above code.

1.User uploads an xml file

2.Parse and display the data from xml to an html table.

3.Finally when user press the button `verify and upload to Application` ,data is inserted to the database.

**Note**
`form` tag is populated along with the html table.

[Sample-xml-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fs7f9ycqclo7ioy/RN-219.xml?dl=0)

[Php-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljenh7c4tbfchma/xml_upload.php?dl=0)

Run the above php file with xml to see the output.

Comment: You speak of XML, but the code is using posted data and does not process XML. Please provide the data that you post via your form, which does not get inserted into the database. You speak of uploading to local server, but what do you mean? Is it inserted in a database on your local host, or did you print the data from PHP? Any, the best is to provide actual data that you are submitting and identify which data is not inserted while it should.

Comment: Im processing XML in another set of code and making the values as POST. I mean that the data is successfully inserted in my local machine's database.

There is no problem with XML fetching. I double checked it. Will it be the problem with my database ? Or how i inserting it to the database ?

Comment: But could you provide data input/output examples with which we can reproduce the problem? Are you saying you have two set-ups: one local host with local database, and one remote host, with remote database, and that it all works fine on the local set-up, but not on the remote set-up?

Comment: Since XML contains sensitive data. I need some time to reproduce it with sample data. Will update question soon with sample input and output

Comment: @trincot  Updated the question with full code and input xml file

Comment: your $third query is based on condition.Are you sure that $third executes every time, there may be records in the table on server